# How to change screen brightness in Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11

How to change screen brightness in Windows 11?

In Settings > Display I don't have such option and in "Network" Settings I can only change sound volume.

Comment: *in "Network" Settings I can only change sound volume.* huh? you change audio volume in network settings? Windows has lost it. Depending on your GPU, you may have some control over brightness through the GPU's settings app

Comment: Windows Display settings included brightness.  Let us see what happens with DISM and SFC.

Comment: Is it a laptop or desktop? As [Microsoft notes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-screen-brightness-in-windows-3f67a2f2-5c65-ceca-778b-5858fc007041#:~:text=an%20external%20monitor.-,To%20change%20the%20brightness%20on%20an%20external%20monitor%2C%20use%20the,slider%20to%20adjust%20the%20brightness.) "*You might not see the Brightness slider on desktop PCs that have an external monitor. To change the brightness on an external monitor, use the buttons on it.*"

Comment: Those brightness settings will only be there for a laptop, and then only for the laptop's built in screen. Any external monitor, connected to either a laptop or a desktop, will need to use its own on screen controls to change brightness.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer is a desktop, or if you are using a laptop but are trying to change the brightness on an external monitor connected to the laptop, you will need to use the brightness controls on the monitor itself.

Only if you're using a laptop, and you're trying to change the brightness on that laptop's built in screen, should you expect to find the brightness controls where you say.

If you are on a laptop, and you're trying to change the built in screen's brightness, and you do not see the brightness controls where you expect, try these methods and steps:

- **Use the hotkeys** most laptops have hotkeys, usually by pressing Fn (function key) and some of the F keys, to control screen brightness. These will vary by laptop and will often be indicated with icons on the special keys.
- **Install updated drivers** update the graphics driver and the function or hotkey drivers from the laptop manufacturer's website. Once again, names will vary by brand, but you should look for drivers that mention they are for the hotkeys or function keys or similar for your specific laptop model.
- **Repair Windows** if the previous steps do not work, repair Windows using the Dism and Sfc (system file checker) tools.